# Reduce `num_classes` from 2 to 1 so AUC/TF/TN/FP/FN metrics work?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, multiclass-classification, auc

I've got some datasets which have two classes. When I try to use certain metrics—e.g., [`tf.keras.metrics.AUC`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC), [`tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/FalseNegatives), [`tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/FalsePositives), [`tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/TrueNegatives) or [`tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/TruePositives)—I get an error akin to:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, None, None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible.
```

I suppose I could use [`tfa.metrics.MultiLabelConfusionMatrix`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/MultiLabelConfusionMatrix) and write my own AUC for PR and ROC. But seriously, I just have two classes. AFAIK, two classes is equivalent to one class.

How do I collapse my tfrecords into one class?

---

To be complete, here is a full working example for recreating this error, starting with imports, globals, and wrangling:

```
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from os import path, mkdir
from shutil import rmtree
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

NUM_CLASSES = 2
INPUT_SHAPE = 32, 32, 3


def create_random_ds(tempdir):
    for class_num in range(NUM_CLASSES):
        directory = path.join(tempdir, 'class{}'.format(class_num))
        mkdir(directory)
        for i in range(20):
            Image \
              .fromarray((np.random.rand(100,100,3) * 255).astype('uint8')) \
              .convert('RGBA') \
              .save(path.join(directory, 'image{}.png'.format(i)))

    return tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        tempdir, labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    )

tempdirs = mkdtemp(), mkdtemp()

train_dataset = create_random_ds(tempdirs[0])
validation_dataset = create_random_ds(tempdirs[1])
```

Then CNN model construction:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(INPUT_SHAPE[0], (INPUT_SHAPE[-1], INPUT_SHAPE[-1]),
                           activation='relu', ),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES)
])
```

And concluding with the meat:

```
try:
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
                  metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC(curve="PR")
                          ])

    model.fit(train_dataset,
              epochs=2,
              validation_data=validation_dataset)
finally:
    for directory in tempdirs:
        rmtree(directory)
```

> ```
> ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible
> ```

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/grouping.py maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change the shape of your model output from 2 to 1, here is what you can do.

Change your model's last line

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES)
```

to

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
```

This will make your model compatible with the AUC metric.

Also, the point to note here is - two classes are equivalent to one class but not the shape of the output layer.
You can train your binary classification model with the output layer having two values instead of one and vice-versa but while calculating values you need to consider the shape.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here. `tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py:173 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
        ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, None, None, 1) vs (None, 1))`. What's the right way to think about propagation of shapes across TensorFlow?

Comment: @AT this is mostly related to your data labels. The code that you've mentioned above is fine to load the data. However, in your actual implementation, you're doing some mistakes. Can't pinpoint exactly without the code. I have used your code and modified it according to my answer and it works great!
From your comment, I can just conclude that you're loading the data incorrectly.